# Google map in visual-force component

Tags: google-maps, salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

The bellow component is giving returning blank(but its printing the value "Hellow all") when used in a visualforce page ..but when used in a plain html in my local machine is returning the map.    Please advice

```
 <apex:component >
    Hello all
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map-canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
      <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
        <style type="text/css">
          html { height: 100% }
          body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
          #map-canvas { height: 100% }
        </style>
         <script type="text/javascript"  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KeyXXXX&sensor=false">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
              center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
              zoom: 8,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
                mapOptions);
          }
          google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
        </script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="map-canvas"/>
      </body>
    </apex:component>
```

Thanks,
Sandy

Answer (score 1):

Trouble is with Salesforce's styles

Embed your component inside a VisualForce page without side bar, headers or styles (standardStylesheets="false" showHeader="false" sidebar="false"), then iframe this page inside another page with all styles, that will work.